# Div with rounded corners and inset border breaks when expanding

Tags: css, safari, webkit

This doesn't seem to be a problem in Firefox. But noticeable in Safari

I have a div with rounded corners, an inset border and a specified width. You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/jsoningram/fek5n/

You'll notice the div breaks about midway down on the left. Well actually it doesn't break but appears to. If I change the color of the border in the .beveled class to black it's visible. I can also remove the border-style and the "missing link" is returned.

The html:

```
<div id="sub_nav" class="rounded_10 beveled">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

​

The css:

```
#sub_nav {
    position: relative;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    width: 164px;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 0px 27px 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

#sub_nav li {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 160px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}

#sub_nav li:first-child {
    margin-top: 27px;
}

    .rounded_10 {
    -webkit-broder-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior:url(_/inc/PIE.htc);
}

    .beveled {
    border: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
    border-style: inset;
}
```

Thanks in advance...​

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how border-style:inset works, and the fact that your border and background colors are so close to one another.

Inset is a 3-d style effect, but with a 1px border, it's having difficulty figuring out how to draw the effect. If you change

```
.beveled {border: 30px solid red; border-style:inset;}
```

You'll see what it's trying to accomplish. It takes the base color and then darkens/lightens it to make the effect. You light grey is getting lightening to white for a section of it.

So, remove the border-style:inset, and then change the border color, and you should be in business.

```
.beveled {border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

Comment: Or use a different color for each side of the border if needed, to simulate a beveled look.

Comment: I'm not sure what his intended look was, but yeah, there are a lot of ways to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of experimenting and found that the same problem appears when you manually create an inset border by setting each side like this.

```
.beveled {
    border-top: 2px solid #aaa;
    border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
    border-right: 2px solid #efefef;
}'
```

I created a jsFiddle with the bare minimum css to show this problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/MdE7q/

It has something to do with the width to height ratio. Can't explain it but change the width on my example to 400px and the gap goes away. In fact the gap doesn't appear at all when width is greater than height, only when height is greater than width.

Also, this looks perfect in IE9+, which leads me to believe it is a rendering problem in webkit and firefox.

Maybe modernizr would help here. http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Wow. This is weird. If you make #sub_nav 180px wide then it seems to fix it.
http://jsfiddle.net/fek5n/11/